# Persisting two data object from different ng-model directives in angularjs and laravel with ngResource

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I have two input fields in my HTML block, `ng-model="book_id"` and `ng-model="borrower_id"`. I also have a button which calls `commit()`. Whenever I click it I want the two id's to be saved in one execution. Is this possible in Angular? I've tried searching but I couldn't find anything. If anyone has an idea I would much appreciate it.

So far this is the snippet I have.

**/app.js/**

```
$scope.commit = function(){
            $scope.$emit('Load')
            Transaction.save({
                'book_id': book.id,
                'borrower_id': lender.lenderID
            }).$promise.then(function(data){
                    if(data.msg){   
                    //angular.copy({}, $scope.book);    
                    $scope.$emit('Unload');
                    $window.location.href='/';
                }
            })  

        };
```

**/API/TransactionController/**

```
class TransactionController extends Controller{

public function store(Request $request){



    $transaction = new Transaction();

    $transaction->book_id = $request->book_id;
    $transaction->lender_id = $request->borrower_id;

    $transaction->save();

    return response()->json([
        'msg' => 'Success',
        '' => $transaction
        ]);
}

}
```

**/html/**

```
<label for="borrowerID"><span class="text-success">Borrower ID</span>   </label>
                                <i ng-show="loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-1x fa-spin"></i>   
                                <input  type="password" name="borrowerID" id="borrowerID" class="form-control" ng-model="lender.lenderID" disabled>

/--book_id--/

<label for="bookID"><span class="text-success">Book ID</span></label>
                                <i ng-show="loading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-1x fa-spin"></i>   
                                <input type="password" name="bookID" id="bookID" class="form-control" ng-model="book.id" disabled>
```

**/Model/Transaction/**

```
class Transaction extends Model
{

protected $table = 'transactions';

protected $fillable = ['book_id', 'borrower_id'];


public function lenders(){

    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Lender');

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe you are missing `$scope` when you pass you data into the api call. Assuming you have this in the controller associated with the HTML template you provided. Does this work:

```
$scope.commit = function(){
            $scope.$emit('Load')
            Transaction.save({
                'book_id': $scope.book.id, // added $scope 
                'borrower_id': $scope.lender.lenderID // added $scope 
            }).$promise.then(function(data){
                    if(data.msg){   
                    //angular.copy({}, $scope.book);    
                    $scope.$emit('Unload');
                    $window.location.href='/';
                }
            })  

        };
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but it doesn't either sir. i've been tweaking it for many times hoping would work out, is it possible to angular to persist two different object at the same time?